# How to open infopath templates in code and change data connections URL

Tags: infopath, data-connections

I need to iterate through infopath templates (xsn files) and change the URL of data connections, and then save the changes to the templates.

The data connections I want to change, points to lists in a sharepoint environment.

So, how could I accomplish this task?

I was thinking doing this with a console application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infopath definitely doesn't make it easy to deploy to different servers. I have used a powershell script but you can use any console app or scripting language.

Steps to follow:
1. Extract the files from the XSN (either use extrac32 util from MS or rename to zip and use any zip library)
2. Change the data connection (string replace) in manifest.xsf, template.xml, and sampledata.xml
3. Repackage the files into the XSN (either use cabarc util from MS or zip and rename)

It is a pain to have to do all that but the entire script is less than a page long and runs pretty fast. One caveat I ran into was I needed a delay between steps 1 and 2 - the files weren't actually finished extracting and my script was trying to change them.